# Can I have more than one feed for facebook instant articles

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-articles

we are implementing feed for facebook instant articles. In Instant Articles Configuration, I only see one input box for submitting RSS Feed URL, can we have more than one feed for facebook instant articles?

Answer (score 1):

You can have **one** production and **one** development RSS feeds.

Remember that RSS feed is solution for simple use cases. If You want have more control and features then use Instant Articles API - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/api

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have actually merged two feeds into one

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you use just one url but your feed can contains how many posts you want to submit.